# Ember - How to sort by transform?

Tags: sorting, ember.js

I am trying to sort a model in Ember by a field that has a transform.  The original field is an IntegerField (served by an API), which is ordered appropriately.  When the field is deserialized by the transform into the string representation, ember sorts by the string, as opposed to the original order.

For instance, if this is the deserialization:

```
{
10: 'Built',
20: 'Started',
30: 'Finished',
};
```

I want this to appear as `Built, Started, Finished` when sorted, according to the original enum.  However, it will actually be sorted as `Built, Finished, Started`, per the alphabetized strings.

Is this possible when using `Ember.computed.sort`?

Comment: is this Array in `Ember.ArrayProxy`?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I am using it in the standard fashion:  my model field refers to the transform, the transform implements the `DS.Transform` `serialize` and `deserialize` methods, and i'm accessing it using a normal controller, `Ember.Controller.extend...` and then applying `Ember.computed.sort` to the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know it is not what you want, but after many search i just do this type of sort on the ember

```
var sortArray = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend(Ember.SortableMixin).create();
sortArray.set("content", []);

sortArray.addObject({"id":10 , "name": 'Built'});
sortArray.addObject({"id":20 , "name": 'Started'});
sortArray.addObject({"id":30 , "name": 'Finished'});

sortArray.set('sortProperties', ["id"]).set("sortAscending", true);
```

Comment: Yeah, this would require me to reproduce all my transforms (and i have a lot).  I can't imagine this is the best solution.

Comment: As it turns out, this is currently the only solution to this problem.  I think Ember should take this use case into consideration, but that's a different issue...  Accepting